# recounting var when i delete characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that remove "disabled" attr of my button when my 2 vars has 3 and 5 characters respectively.

But when I deleted my characters it doesnt count back, and add again the "disabled" attr to my button.
I dont know how to do it. Any suggestions ?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/CCwKp/

HTML

```
<form action="" method="" class="login">
    <ul class="userLogin">
        <li>
            <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="user" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" class="pass" />
         </li>
       </ul>
    <button disabled />test</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    var user = 0;
    var pass = 0;

    function userPassAlert() {
        if (user >= 3 && pass >=5) {
            $('button').removeClass('disabled').addClass('available').removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $('button').removeClass('available').addClass('disabled').attr("disabled");
        }
    };

    $(".user").on('focus keypress', function() {
        user++;
        console.log(user);
        userPassAlert();
    });
    $(".pass").on('focus keypress', function() {
        pass++;
        console.log(pass);
        userPassAlert()
    });

    $('button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (user >= 3 && pass >=5) {
            alert("done");
        }
        else {
           return false; 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: should use `prop()` not `attr()` for `disabled` see jQuery docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. To add the "disabled" attribute back to the button, it has to be added as such:

   `$(".this").attr("disabled","disabled");`
2. The counter is always adding to the user/pass when there is a mouse click or keypress so it will always go up and never down.  If we change this to check the length of the value in the input when there is a mouse or key action, it will verify the actual length existing in the input field.  You can do this by using:

   `user=$(".user").val().length;`
3. Keyup is better to handle backspace than keypress.  Replacing this in your "on" functions will provide a more accurate result.

[JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FW4tw/%20JS%20Fiddle%20Here)

Answer (score 1):

You increment the `user` and `pass` on every keypress, even if you remove a character. I 
would instead check the length of the values in the fields in your method `userPassAlert()`:

```
function userPassAlert() {
    if ($('.user').val().length >= 3 && $('.pass').val().length >=5) {
        $('button').removeClass('disabled').addClass('available').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('button').removeClass('available').addClass('disabled').prop("disabled", true);
    }
};
```